# .net Protobuf Compiler can i prevent capitalizing first letter of proto file on the auto-generated class

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, grpc

We have a csproj, with the following .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Test.v1;
option csharp_namespace = "Test";

message TestMsg {
  string name = 1;
}
```

We are using the .net grpc tools, Build Action of "Protobuf compiler".  The Generated class capitalizes the first leter, i.e., name -> Name.

Is there any way to mantain the lowercase first letter? (the reason being that we have an internal naming convention that we would prefer to keep).

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

The protocol buffers compiler (which *Grpc.Tools* uses) will always generate C# files with Pascal-case names (i.e. first letter capitalized). There are no options to stop this from happening. (See [names.cc](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/e5679c01e8f47e8a5e7172444676bda1c2ada875/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/names.cc#L63) for where it is done in the compiler).

Comment: Thanks! so i see 3 options: 1) Modify names.cc and recompile for our case. 2) Postprocess the output to change the Pascal to camelcase. 3) accept the change and incur in huge changes on our platform. As our DTOs are very simple using just primitive types, do you think option 1 is viable or too risky?

Comment: Modifying protocol buffers is probably a bad idea and may lead to incompatibilities in the future.  You could add some customs build steps to your csproj file (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md#bypassing-grpctools-to-run-the-protocol-buffers-compiler-explicitly) ) but you'll lose the some of the incremental build logic that Grpc.Tools tries to do.

Comment: Thanks, What about using messages holding  just a byte array of a serialized DTO class with, say, MemoryPack ? I know this prevents discoverability, however in our case, we are solely interested in an efficient transport between server and client, which has the BR layer and can deserialized the data.